# I can't setup socket in my page with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I setup socket in client at my page with url

> /localhost:3000/post/:id

In client I set

```
socket=io("http://localhost"3000/post/:id")
```

but when I listen in server with `io.on("connection")` , it isn't active.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should configure it :

```
   var app = require('express')();
   var http = require('http').createServer(app);
   var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Read this documentation to understand it better https://socket.io/docs/v3

Answer (score 0):

In the client side you just need to include the socket.io cdn file and when you are on same host you don't have to include the full url.
code sample for client side :

```
let socket = io.connect();
socket.emit("connection",{});
```

For better understanding please view documentation as said on previous comment.